# Cascade tree of file numbers

Tags: linux, scripting, filesystems, macos

Standard output of `tree` contains the information about hierarchy of files. The tool contains the option to do that with sizes adding the sizes of all files and displaying folders only (`tree --du -h`) allowing to discover big directories.

I'm looking for the same thing, but for number of files to discover hot spots of not-so-big directories with hundreds of thousands of files in a large tree.

Comment: What is your criteria for "not so big"? If you want to output directories that are smaller than a certain size, then you are better off using `find`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Original Version**

You only need to do one sweep of the filesystem for the `-type`s you are interested in and then aggregate by the containing folder and count.

```
find . -type f ! -type l 2>/dev/null | sed "s|/[^/]*$||g" | sort | uniq -c | awk '$1>=1000'
```

Using the `/etc` benchmark @ threshhold of 50

```
    109 .
     96 ./apparmor.d/abstractions
    138 ./ca-certificates/extracted/cadir
     64 ./fonts/conf.avail
     81 ./sane.d
     58 ./xdg

real    0m0.014s
user    0m0.015s
sys     0m0.018s
```

**Counter Espionage Version**

Since war seems to have broken out, I thought I would optimise my own armory and, in the best traditions of wartime counter espionage, have stolen `%h\n` outrageously.

```
find . -type f ! -type l -printf '%h\n' 2>/dev/null | 
   awk '{dir[$1]++}
        END{for (d in dir) if (dir[d] >=50) print dir[d], d}'|
   sort -g

58 ./xdg
64 ./fonts/conf.avail
81 ./sane.d
96 ./apparmor.d/abstractions
109 .
138 ./ca-certificates/extracted/cadir

real    0m0.006s
user    0m0.005s
sys     0m0.005s
```

Since the execution time for this is less than my key bounce for small directories and my entire (2TB) filesystem is dealt with in ~1.5s, I think the typing overhead is in my favour for an off the cuff one-liner.

Though I defer graciously to the blazing speed of the solution by Glorious @haukelaging

;)

**Post Script** my whole FS

Moi

```
real    0m1.481s
user    0m0.975s
sys     0m0.805s
```

Toi

```
real    0m1.586s
user    0m1.069s
sys     0m0.843s
```

Comment: What do you need the `sed -E` for?

Comment: Decoration? E's are good? Brain failure? Please take your pick.

Answer (score 2):

That seems not possible with `tree` but you can do this:

### slow version

```
find . -type d -exec bash -c 'printf "%7d   " '\
'$(find "$1" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -not -type l -printf . | wc -m); '\
'printf "%s\n" "$1"' find {} \; 2>/dev/null |
awk '$1>1000'
```

Prints the file numbers (in this case only those greater than 1,000) and directory paths.

Executed in my /etc (with file count threshold 50) outputs this:

```
    175   .
     70   ./sysconfig
     98   ./apparmor.d/abstractions
     84   ./gconf/gconf.xml.schemas
    122   ./brltty/Text
     76   ./sane.d
```

### fast version

bu5hman's answer made me realize that I hadn't noticed how slow this is.

So this is an optimized version of the other approach:

```
find . -type f -not -type l -printf '%h\n' 2>/dev/null |
  awk -v th=50 '{ a[$0]++; }; '\
  'END { PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@unsorted"; for (key in a) if (a[key]<th) delete a[key];'\
  ' PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_num_desc";for (key in a) printf "%7d   %s\n",a[key],key }'
```

```
    175   .
    122   ./brltty/Text
     98   ./apparmor.d/abstractions
     84   ./gconf/gconf.xml.schemas
     76   ./sane.d
     70   ./sysconfig
```

`awk` can do not just the filtering but also the counting and sorting. And it can do that in the right order: count, filter, sort. Whereas sort, count, filer is the worst. Of course, this matters only with huge directory numbers whereas the difference between

1. a large number of processes moving little data and
2. a small number or processes moving more data

is remarkable even with the 400+ directories in /etc and the (probably) 100% page cache hit rate for the subprocesses.